# HTML tags are not allowed in footer copyright

Tags: adminhtml, html, magento-2.1.8

I just wanted to change my theme config and it gives me this error on **Footer Copyright** section:

> HTML tags are not allowed.

**=> Screenshot :** [image: Magento 2.1 Footer Copyright HTML Tag Not Allowed]

But if I make this copyright empty and Save the configuration, This error will not show anymore and configuration save would be successfully. but after returning to configuration page default value of copyright will be pulled there and I cant save configuration again.

I tried to upgrade **Magento to 2.1.8 version** (by composer) and changing theme to default Magento theme (Magento Black), but nothing changed!

can you please help me how to solve this error?

I need hyperlink in my copyright section, so how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento have set validation to not allowed html tags in copyright box(ex - validate-no-html-tags) . So default it won't allowed you to add html tags.

**But if you still want to add the html tags in copyright box then, below are the steps :**

1) you need to override the **design_config_form.xml** in your **custom module**

2) Copy design_config_form.xml file from

> **"vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml"**

and paste it to your **custom module directory** like this

> **"Magento2RootDirectory/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml"**

3) Open the file and go to the bottom **line no - 268** , You will find `<item name="validate-no-html-tags" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>` , Just modify it by **false**
like this `"<item name="validate-no-html-tags" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>"`

4) After that run below command

```
4.1 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4.2 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
4.3 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
4.4 php bin/magento cache:clean
4.5 php bin/magento cache:flush
```

5) Now open your admin panel by logged in with credentials and **go to Content->configuration->theme edit->Footer section again-> now it will allowed you to add html tags**.

[image]

Hope it helps you

Comment: no such file in luma theme

Comment: although this works, it is bad practice to copy the entire core file into a module - only copy what you intent to overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

I have created extension for that and you can use.

[Allow HTML tags in footer copyright](https://github.com/nadeem0035/allow-html-tags)